# Bash script that can output specific parts of a tacacs file into columns

Tags: linux, bash, columns, output

I'm trying to output parts of a tacacs file into a monthly report.

Have tried doing it in python but my result still has errors, so I thought I'd try and see if there's a elegant solution within a simple-ish bash script.

Among other things in the file, the bits that I want out of the file look like this:

```
user = user1 {
      member = group2
 }

user = user2 {
      member = group3
 }
```

Now ideally what I want, is all the members that are part of say, group2, outputted into a column and in another column, have the name of the group they're in.

I can handle the emailing monthly part, it's just the output I'm experiencing issues with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/user =/ { u = $3 } /member =/ { print u, $3 }' file
user1 group2
user2 group3
```

If we find a line matching `user =`, then remember the user name (this is take from the third whitespace-delimited field).  When we find a line matching `member =`, output the remembered user name along with the third field from this line (which ought to be the group name).

I'm unfamiliar with the file format and I don't know what else may be present in this file, so I can't say that this would work on any other data than what's presented in the question.

Comment: That works pretty well, I replaced member= with the group name and it returns everyone that is in that group.

Is there anyway to add formatting to both columns and add headers at the top?

Comment: Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).